# how to check what class is the object in c#

Tags: c#, class, object

Say I have a list of objects called components:

```
List<object> components = new List<object>();
```

Say it's populated with objects of the classes engine, wheel, frame. Now, I want to make a function that takes a class as a parameter and returns true if the list has an object of that class. Like this:

```
public static bool HasComponent( *the class* ) { 
    foreach(object c in components) {
        if(c is *the class*)
           return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

How do i go about doing that? is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
public static bool HasComponent<T>() { 
    foreach(object c in components) {
        if(c is T)
           return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Call it:

```
Obj.HasComponent<Wheel>();
```

Answer (score 5):

use linq:

```
components.OfType<YouType>().Any();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call GetType() to get the type of any object in .Net or use the `is` keyword. Indeed, you could do this on the list using LINQ with something like:

```
components.Any(x => x is Wheel);
```

and substitute `Wheel` for the desired type.

Answer (score 1):

Something more like this

```
public static bool HasComponent<TheType>() 
{  
    foreach(object c in components) 
    { 
        if(c is TheType) 
        {
           return true; 
        }
    }  
    return false; 
}
```

Or shorter

```
public static bool HasComponent<TheType>() 
{  
    return components.OfType<TheType>().Count() > 0;
}
```

Call it with

```
 HasComponent<TheType>()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know some answers suggested using the "is" keyword, but you'll want to be careful in inheritance situations. e.g. If Cow derives from Animal, then `HasComponent<Cow>()` will return true for both. You should really compare types to avoid the problem:

```
public static bool HasComponent<T>()
{
    return components.Any(i => i.GetType() == typeof(T));
}
```

Of course, you can do it without generics by passing in a type, but generics is really the way to go:

```
public static bool HasComponent(Type type)
{
    return components.Any(i => i.GetType() == type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find this out, we should use an extended for loop that is 'foreach', which traverses through all types of class objects and checks the desired object of specific class and returns either true or false.

```
public static bool HasComponent<Type>()  { 
foreach(object c in l) {
    if(object c in Type)
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a multiple-threaded application, you should be sure that the object is in the list at the time you search for it. Because the other thread can remove this object at the same time as the search. So, a NullReferenceException could be thrown. In order to avoid this situation, you can use this function.

```
 public static bool HasComponent<T>()
 {
    foreach (object c in components)
    {
       lock (c.GetType())
       {
           if (c is T)
           {
              return true;
           }
       }

     }
     return false;
}
```

But, to call this function your list should be static.